# Copy folder which has date associated in the foldername from one location to other location using vb script

Tags: vbscript

I have a folder with name like "Shared1_1_12_2015".
The foldername will change based on the date.
So how to copy this folder and paste it as "Shared1" in the same location using VB Script?
For backup purpose, I am doing this task.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: So each day you want to run this once and copy the folder Shared1_<current month>_<current day>_<current year> to Shared1?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please make it more clear according to folder tree structure. If i am not wrong let me understand it by this way...

C:/Shared1_1_12_2015

C:/Shared1_2_12_2015

C:/...

So you want to copies all these folder to same location C:/**Shared1**

But see here main problem is every time **Shared1** folder will be overwritten by new latested 'Shared1_'